# Self-Referencing Constructor. Does this pattern smell?

Tags: c#, design-patterns

I'm doing a code review for a *senior* developer and they've implemented quite a curious design pattern.

```
public class A : ABase
{
    private ABase aBase { get; }
    public A(A a)
    {
        aBase = a;
    }
    public A () {}
    //loads of stuff depending on aBase being initialised
}
```

The A() constructor is used throughout, then the constructed object is passed back into the A(A) constructor like this

```
var a = new A();
//a is not usable at this point.
var b = new A(a);
//b is usable.
```

My question: Is this a legitimate design pattern? And if not, how does a junior developer approach a *senior* developer doing something crazy to the code base.

Comment: Let's not use the term "ctor".  For clarity, just type out "constructor".

Comment: As you wish, Rory.

Comment: Yes, the whole point of a constructor is to put the object in a valid state, which the parameterless one does not do.

Comment: @Lee how doesn't it?  How do you know it's not in a valid state from the info given?

Comment: "not usable" is a vague phrase.  For example, if I have a builder pattern, I can construct an object but it won't be "usable" until many steps later, after I've called the builder methods with different args.

Comment: @rory.ap `//loads of stuff depending on aBase being initialised`

Comment: @rory.ap - The parameterless constructor does not set `aBase` while the comment suggests the rest of the class assumes it has been assigned. It's not clear how the constructed one is initialised from the code presented.

Comment: @Lee -- Ahh, I see your point.

Comment: @Lee -- Then I would say, if anything, this breaks SRP

Comment: To his credit, I've not seen `var a = new A(new A());` but it's possible.

Comment: Using a property setter when it doesn't have one can't be right of course.  This is otherwise known as a "copy constructor" in C++ lingo.  Albeit that you'd normally expect it to deep-copy the passed object.  It isn't wrong.

Comment: From what you've shown us, the code certainly isn't self-explanatory. I'd say to the person, "This doesn't make sense to me / what problem is it solving / there must be a more self-documenting approach." A static factory method `A.NewAdjectiveA(){ return new A(new A())} ` and make the `A()` private would result in code that hides the unusuable A, and can describe in the method name what `new A( newA())` means

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is this a legitimate design pattern?

Yes. This looks a lot like the [Decorator](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/479635/UnderstandingplusandplusImplementingplusDecoratorp) pattern where you use composition to add behavior to your class without exploding your API with too many subclasses. Whether the pattern is appropriate in your context depends on the rest of the code that you have not shown us.

The statement `var b = new A(a);` is said to decorate the existing instance of `A` with additional behavior. Compare this with the [Strategy](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/776819/Strategy-Pattern-Csharp) pattern where you create a new subclass for each permutation/combination of behavior.

> And if not, how does a junior developer approach a senior developer
>   doing something crazy to the code base

This question is out of scope for StackOverflow. But if I have to answer that, the right approach would be to read up as much as you can and approach your senior with an open mind.

Comment: I would not recommend following this example to learn the Decorator Pattern. The `A()` constructor is inappropriate, and the `A(A a)` constructor would be more useful as `A(ABase base)`.

Comment: @jaco0646 Patterns are documented versions of common design problems. That does not mean they need to be followed word to word. You don't need to *learn* patterns per-se. The `A(a a)` constructor allows one to restrict the type to only `A` or its subclasses which is possible use case.

Answer (score 1):

I've got it. 
The class needs to either:

1. Use inheritance correctly, reference 'this' internally, and remove the private ABase property and related constructor.
2. Not use inheritance and use IoC (StructureMap in our case) to initialise an instance of the base class, removing the A() constructor.

As for approaching him, I just walked over and gave him these two options... I guess it's much easier when you have the answer.

Comment: I am curios to know what he said. See my answer because even if your senior did manage to mess up the design in your application, there is actually nothing wrong with the approach if used correctly.

Comment: He didn't really say much, just "Oh... I'll update that." I think he might have been abusing the pattern for the sake of 'unit' tests... that were actually integration tests... (shrug, he's a relatively new hire).

Comment: There could be a possibility that you don't have enough knowledge or experience at the moment  to understand why something like that was done. Keep an open mind ;). Besides, writing unit tests actually promotes good design and testability is an important attribute of quality code :). Just saying!

Answer (score 0):

It certainly is odd, given that I don't know more information about what it's used for, but there's nothing wrong with relating two instances of the same class by injecting one instance into another in its constructor.  It doesn't appear to break [Liskov](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle).